# How to view Cosmos DB size?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

For a SQL database, I can easily see the size of the database in the Overview blade in Azure Portal. Or I can query for instance `EXEC sp_spaceused` to find out.

Is there such a thing for Cosmos DB?

Comment: If you mean total storage consumed storage, you can see it in metric blade in azure portal. The same as what @Vova said below, here's the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics#compare-data-size-against-index-size).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search for Monitor -> Metrics -> Select Scope (Your cosmos) -> Select Metric( Data Usage or Index Usage)

The other way go to cosmosdb -> Metrics(Classic)

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to go under Containers Menu -> Browse.

This view shows storage based on each container, cost, throughput. Also, it gives you the total of all of these.

[image]